# Lua loop knowing when loops ends

Tags: loops, lua

Is there a statement in Lua that would allow me to determinate whether it's last loop cycle?
When I'm not able to determinate how many time loop will loop?

Example:

```
for _, v in pairs(t) do
if I_know_this_is_your_last_cycle then
-- do something
end
```

Comment: Do you mean `break` statement?  Yes, it exists in Lua.

Comment: Can you give a better example of why you would need to do this? What you are doing is a bit of a code smell for me...

Comment: No, I know about break, but break only ends the loop. Sorry my example is bad.

for _, v in pairs(t) do
if _ == last_cycle_statement then
-- do something
end

I'm looking for "last_cycle_statement" if it exists of course.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simplified version of missingno's answer:  :-)

```
for _, v in pairs(t) do
  if next(t,_) == nil then
    -- do something in last cycle
  end
end
```

Comment: Where is missingno's answer?

Comment: @FaheemMitha `hugomg == missingno` (it's his old nickname as of 2013)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I didn't think of a name change.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. As you can see from the [Lua docs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.5), the for loop is syntax sugar for a while loop on top of an iterator so it only knows  if the loop is over at the start of the loop.

If you really want to check if you are entering the last iteration then I would simply code things explicitly with an while loop.

```
local curr_val = initial_value
while curr_val ~= nil then
    local next_val = get_next(initial_value)
    if next_val ~= nil then
       --last iteration
    else
       --not last iteration
    end
    curr_val = next_val
end
```

If you want to translate the example with the `pairs` function, you can use the [next](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-next) function as the iterator.

---

As an aside, I would suggest thinking twice before coding a loop like this one. The way its coded means its very easy to write code that doesn't work right when you are iterating over 0 or 1 elements or to write code that doesn't treat the last element properly. Most of the time writing a plain loop and putting the "at the end"  code *after* the loop is more reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try to write something like this:

```
    --count how many elements you have in the table
    local element_cnt = 0
    for k,v in pairs(t) do
      element_cnt = element_cnt + 1
    end


    local current_item = 1
    for k,v in pairs(t)
       if current_item == element_count then
         print  "this is the last element"
       end
       current_item = current_item + 1
    end
```

or this:

```
local last_key = nil
for k,v in pairs(t) do
   last_key = k
end

for k,v in pairs(t) do
  if k == last_key then
--this is the last element
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. The easiest is to just use the standard for loop and check it yourself, like this:

```
local t = {5, nil, 'asdf', {'a'}, nil, 99}
for i=1, #t do
    if i == #t then
        -- this is the last item.
    end
end
```

Alternatively, you could roll your own iterator function for tables that tells you when you're on the last item, something like this:

```
function notifyPairs(t)
    local lastItem = false
    local i = 0
    return
      function()
        i = i + 1
        if i == #t then lastItem = true end;
        if (i <= #t) then
            return lastItem, t[i]
        end
      end
end

for IsLastItem, value in notifyPairs(t) do
    if IsLastItem then 
        -- do something with the last item
    end
end
```

Comment: The first snippet of code will work only for tables indexed with consecutive integers starting from one.

Comment: yeah, he didn't give an example of his table so i'm assuming he's building his tables like i am above (auto-generated indices).